# Populate table from separate file of unknown length based on cell value in 2nd file

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a file that contains a load of data that's a dump from a database and one of the columns lists a location name as the cell value.  This database file will grow every day and I have no way of knowing how large it'll be.  So I'll never know the range.
Now I have a file for each location and I need to populate that file with all the entries from the database file that match the location name.

I'm not sure where to start exactly. I'm thinking something to do with vlookup and index but not sure.
Any tips?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: added what my Get External data looks like.
[Get external Data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP14l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I have a super massive file of interesting data in a folder called QueryByFile, and my file contains a very long list of locations and each location has a super interesting number:

[image]

If I wanted to separate the data from the super massive file into separate files based on the value in the Location column, I would do this:

First, close the super massive file. Next, create a new file with the name 'New York.xlsx' in the same folder. In the New York file, select 'Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook' then select the super massive file of interesting data in the file browser dialog. In the Navigator window, select the sheet or table of data that has the location in it:

[image]

Push the 'Transform Data' button to edit the query.

Filter the location column so that only 'New York' is showing.

Click 'Close & Load' on the ribbon to load the New York data into the New York file. You should now have all your New York data in the New York file:

[image]

Repeat this process for all locations. It will help if you Copy/Paste the New York file, rename it, then just edit the Query to filter to a different location instead of starting from scratch each time.

If you have so many locations as to make this a very tedious process, you could parameterize the file name and set the query to read the file name as the filter. That is a little more involved though, so perhaps the above will suffice.

When new data are added to the master file (whose name should not change), you can simply right click the table in each location file and select 'Refresh' to get the latest data for that location.

Comment: Looks promising but my excell doesn't have a "Get Data>from file> from workbook" method.  It is office 2013 and offers From Access, Web, Text, other sources.  Digging through those doesn't show anything with a workbook or the ability to filter the workbook.  I really like your method tho so Imma try to keep poking at it.  It looks super simple and ideal :) (Added a pic of what my get external data looks like to the OP)

Comment: Adding in as an xlm and a table is nice but it imports the whole workbook.  Which i can filter as a table but it still has all the rest of the data there. If a user just unfilters it they have the rest of the data which is excess and undesired.

Comment: Try activating the Power Query addin. That will give you more options. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a#ID0EAAHAAA=Office_2013

Comment: Oh that's neat.  Shame I can't install the addin (company security).

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't have Excel 2013 so difficult to test but you might try either the XML option (since Excel files are actually XML files) or the Microsoft Query option.

Comment: After all that work it turns out I have to rethink it all.  Can't 'share' a linked Table or XML map.